# How are user and session info being queried with this refresh token?

Tags: authentication, token, okta, refresh-token

Recently I have been studying authentication, encryption, hashing, etc. When I was going through the [okta docs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/main/) I noticed this curl

```
http --form POST https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default/v1/token \
  accept:application/json \
  authorization:'Basic MG9hYmg3M...' \
  cache-control:no-cache \
  content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded \
  grant_type=refresh_token \
  redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080 \
  scope=offline_access%20openid \
  refresh_token=MIOf-U1zQbyfa3MUfJHhvnUqIut9ClH0xjlDXGJAyqo
```

this curl returns

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJ[...]K1Sun9bA",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "offline_access%20openid",
    "refresh_token": "MIOf-U1zQbyfa3MUfJHhvnUqIut9ClH0xjlDXGJAyqo",
    "id_token": "eyJraWQiO[...]hMEJQX6WRQ"
}
```

So, now the question is how is this refresh token is being used to query the database for user details, user sessions, etc? What I have observed is that the refresh token length is 43 characters in base64url encoding format, converting it to hex it becomes 64 characters. Using the AES-256-cbc algorithm and encrypting base64 encoded UUID (which is pk and contains session details) results in an encrypted token with hex 64 characters. But then the question is where are the IV/nonce and salts are being stored? If the refresh token is not an encrypted token, then how such a long string is queried in the DB with more than a million entries regularly without any possible delay? I know indexing can be possible but wouldn't that be a costly decision with all the space indexing occupies?

Asking this question out of curiosity.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh token is opaque one, so it doesn't contain any information in it.

You can read more here - https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/main/#about-refresh-tokens

To get information about the user, you can user `/userinfo` endpoint, described here - https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#userinfo. But it required `access_token` not the refresh one. So you need first to get an access token with the help of your refresh token from `/token` endpoint, again well described here - https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#token, and only after that call `/userinfo`

As for the question of effectiveness of data manipulation and storage, from my perspective one of the solutions can be calculating the hash of the token and using it as a key in the storage (if it's even required).

I think your question may have little bit misleading tags, if your interest lies in the area of information data structures and algorithms

Comment: Sir my question is how do you query user data with this refresh token, if its opaque?

Comment: Yeah that's right and makes much sense "the solutions can be calculating the hash of the token and using it as a key in the storage" never thought about it